# "error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods" in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, menu, keycode

I am working on a game in unity and in the script for controlling the buttons in the game mode menu.
While writing this error occurred:
*error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods* and i have no idea whats wrong.
Heres the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SecondaryMenuControl : MonoBehaviour
{

public bool isSurvival;  
public bool isSelectLevel;
public bool isGoBack;


} 

 // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

void OnMouseUp(){
    if(isSurvival)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(MainScene);
    }

    if (isSurvival)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SelectLevelMenu);
    }

    if (isGoBack)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(IntroMenu);  
    }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Regards,
Keno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the stray bracket;

```
public class SecondaryMenuControl : MonoBehaviour
{

public bool isSurvival;  
public bool isSelectLevel;
public bool isGoBack;


} // remove this one!

// rest of the file
```

The error basically saids 'You defined some properties/fields/methods in a namespace' which you of course can't do. They all belong inside a class.

edit: this should be your output:

```
public class SecondaryMenuControl : MonoBehaviour
{

public bool isSurvival;  
public bool isSelectLevel;
public bool isGoBack;

private void OnMouseUp(){
    if(isSurvival)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(MainScene);
    }

    if (isSurvival)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SelectLevelMenu);
    }

    if (isGoBack)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(IntroMenu);  
    }

} // end of OnMouseUp
} // end of class
```

make sure you match an opening bracket with a closing one.

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)